# Functional Equation $G(x^2) = \frac{1}{2} (G(x) + G(-x))$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, functional-equations

I am working on this problem to find all functions $f:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = f(2x)$. Specifically, I am trying to work out the generating function for this problem. I found the following relationship for the generating function $G(x^2) = \frac{1}{2} (G(x) + G(-x))$.

$$
G(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f(k) x^k 
$$
$$
G(x)= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f(2k)x^{2k} + f(2k-1)x^{2k-1}
$$
$$
G(x)= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f(k)x^{2k} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f(2k-1)x^{2k-1}
$$
$$
G(x)= G(x^2) + \frac{G(x)-G(-x)}{2}
$$
$$
G(x^2) = \frac{1}{2} (G(x) + G(-x))
$$

I tried to find a way to solve this functional equation online but could not find anything. What is G(x), and what are the coefficients of the polynomial form of G(x)?

Edit

An example of a function that satisfys $f(x) = f(2x)$ is
$$
f(x) = \sin(2 \pi log_2(x)))
$$

Comment: Functions *from where to where*? (I mean, with what (co)domain?) I see tags "number theory" and "p-adic number theory" which I do not find related to the question.

Comment: If you take continuous functions at $0$, the only functions verifying $f(2x)=f(x)$ are the constant since $f(x)=f(x/2^j)$ for all $j$ and all $x$.

Comment: We don't generally discuss generating functions in terms of continuous functions, but only functions on the natural numbers or, sometimes on integers.

Comment: Just updated the problem, f should map from the natural numbers to real numbers

Comment: If $H(x)$ is any odd function and $$G(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} H\left(x^{2^j}\right)$$ for all $x$ in some interval around $0,$ then $G(x)$ is such a function.

In particular, if $H(x)=x K(x)$ where $K(x)$ is even and bounded bear $0,$ $G$ will always converge in the intersection of that interval and $[-1,1].$

Other functions $H$ work near zero, too, however. $H(x)=\sqrt[2m+1]x$ works, for example. You definitely need $H(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0$ for convergence.

Comment: Given $G,$ we can determine $H$ by $H(x)=G(x)-G(x^2).$

Comment: Thanks for the update, but isn't it obvious that the original problem gets solved like this: Those functions $f$ are in bijecton with all sequences of real numbers $(a_1, a_2, ...)$ via setting $f(2n-1):=a_n$, and $f(2n):=f(n)$? What's the use of making that answer more complicated via generating functions? Also, I still don't see the point of the tags I mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $G(x)$ with $G(x^2)=\frac{G(x)+G(-x)}{2},$ define $H(x)=G(x)-G(x^2).$

Then $$\begin{align}H(-x)&=G(-x)-G(x^2)\\&=(G(-x)+G(x))-G(x)-G(x^2)\\&=2G(x^2)-G(x^2)-G(x)\\&=G(x^2)-G(x)\\&=-H(x).\end{align}$$

So $H$ is an odd function.

If $G$ is continuous at $0,$ then $H(x)\to 0$ as $x\to 0,$ so we get:

$$H(x)+H(x^2)+H(x^4)+H(x^{2^n})=G(x)-G(x^{2^{n+1}})\to G(x)-G(0)$$ as $n\to\infty.$

On the other hand, if $g_0$ is a real number and $H(x)$ is an odd function such that, on some interval around $0,$ $$G(x)=g_0+\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} H\left(x^{2^j}\right)$$ converges, then $G$ is such a function.

This reduces to your problem about $f.$ If $f(2k)=f(k),$ then $f$ is entirely determined by the value of $f$ on odd $k,$ and we can start with literally any function on the odd values.

Then $$H(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f(2k+1)x^{2k+1}$$ is the odd function.

There are other $H$ which work which do not have power series near zero, however. For example, $H(x)=\sqrt[2n+1]x$ still has $G(x)$ converging on $(-1,1).$